# React - How to navigate from a plain class (no Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I have a plain class (meaning it doesn't extend from React.Component), and I want to go to a new route):

```
class CalculatorService {

  constructor() {
  }

  sum(a, b){ return a+b; }
  minus(a, b){ return a-b; }
  goSomeWhere(){ GO TO HOME PAGE. What do I put here? }

}

export default CalculatorService;
```

Of course I import this class into React components and use its functions from there, and when I execute `goSomeWhere` it should go to a different page, even though this class is a logic class and has nothing to do with React.

My solutions so far is to use a library called `react-navigation` to no avail because I didn't understand it. I also tried passing a function into the constructor so it could call some Component's method where navigation is possible. But none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

The idea isn't to call the route change within the `CalculatorService` class but getting the `callback` or `return` response from the class to be notified of the moment when you would like to change the route (of course you don't necessarily have to be 'notified' if all your codes are synchronous) and making the route change in the `React` component.

As to programmatically changing the route, do refer to my another answer [Stateless component React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895607/stateless-component-react-router/50895645#50895645)